# Drawable-hdpi, Drawable-mdpi, Drawable-ldpi Android

Tags: android, image

I was working on Android 1.5, but I have now moved to the latest version. So there is only one "drawable" folder in Android 1.5, but now there are three different folders for storing images in the Android project.

And I have found some articles for these three folders that says

1. hdpi means High-dpi
2. mdpi means medium-dpi
3. ldpi means low-dpi

But what is the exact purpose of these three folders and when should I use a particular folder to store images in?

Comment: may be this link helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16706076/font-size-and-images-for-different-devices

Answer (score 27):

To declare different layouts and bitmaps you'd like to use for the different screens, you must place these alternative resources in separate directories/folders.

This means that if you generate a `200x200` image for `xhdpi` devices, you should generate the same resource in `150x150` for `hdpi`, `100x100` for `mdpi`, and `75x75` for `ldpi` devices.

Then, place the files in the appropriate drawable resource directory:

```
MyProject/
    res/
        drawable-xhdpi/
            awesomeimage.png
        drawable-hdpi/
            awesomeimage.png
        drawable-mdpi/
            awesomeimage.png
        drawable-ldpi/
            awesomeimage.png
```

Any time you reference `@drawable/awesomeimage`, the system selects the appropriate bitmap based on the screen's density.

Comment: Just an addendum - the [recommended] ratio between ldpi, mdpi, hdpi and xhdpi is 3:4:6:8. That explains how the image values in the answer came about.

Answer (score 0):

I got one good solution. Here I have attached it as the image below. So try it. It may be helpful to you...!

[image]

Comment: this answer should be text