# Android : Drawable-hdpi, Drawable-mdpi, Drawable-ldpi?

Tags: android, android-image

Can anyone briefly explain to me about what are the differentiation for these (Drawable - hdpi, ldpi, mdpi)  folders? And, where will i store the images for using that in layouts? Thanks in advance.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3263265/drawable-hdpi-drawable-mdpi-drawable-ldpi-android

Comment: Similar link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6166677/android-screen-size-hdpi-ldpi-mdpi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are to declaratively suport [multiple screen resolutions](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html), without need to write resolution-dependent code.