# Different size of Drawable when loaded as background from /drawable-hdpi instead of /drawable

Tags: android, android-widget, drawable

I moved 9-patch files from `/drawable` to `/drawable-hdpi` because the error log recommended to use `drawable-*` to offer density optimized images.

The problem is, that the `AppWidget` now looks different. When `Drawables` are stored in `/drawable-hdpi` the border is thicker.

For more information compare the attached screenshots. What is the reason for this difference?

**Screenshot**

[image]

**Layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/widget_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/widget_bg" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="@string/widget_loading"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <ProgressBar
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView1" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Drawable** `@drawable/widget_bg_default`

[image]

**widget_bg** (stored in `/drawables`)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/widget_bg_default" android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="false" android:state_selected="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/widget_bg_pressed" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:state_selected="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/widget_bg_focused" android:state_focused="true"/>

</selector>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the explanation to the whole android drawable directory structure

[Drawable-hdpi, Drawable-mdpi, Drawable-ldpi Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3263265/drawable-hdpi-drawable-mdpi-drawable-ldpi-android)

also

http://wonton-games.blogspot.com/2010/07/tutorial-multiple-screen-support.html

Comment: @SargeBorsch  yeah, I guess they removed it.

Comment: maybe this will help http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html