# android display picture - ok on 4.4 not seen on 5.1

Tags: android, image, layout

I have two activities. In one jpeg fullHD picture is added via ImageView, in other same picture via backgound to root layout. Both are displayed correctly on Studio 1.4 design view and on device Android 4.4 with smaller then FullHD screen, my colleage tested app on couple other devices - ok. However, AFAIK same builds on Android 5.1 FullHD screen shows just black in both activities. Tried to load converted to png picture - same black area.

What could be the issue with last device? Code just in case below:

```
LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background_pic_1080x1920"
    android:orientation="vertical">
```

and

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/main_backgroundImage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/background_fullhd" />
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33204925/imageview-is-not-shown-in-nexus-5-android-6-0

Answer (score 0):

@IntelliJ Amiya in comment pointed me to right direction. 
Link [imageView is not shown in Nexus 5 (Android 6.0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33204925/imageview-is-not-shown-in-nexus-5-android-6-0) has answer to by issue though I have 5.1, not 6.0.

I checked logcat and I too had:

```
W/OpenGLRenderer: Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture (3240x5760, max=4096x4096)
```

Seems strange to me about size as screen is 1920x1080, however putting picture in `drawable-nodpi` folder in `res` solved my issue.