# Android Layout Design ldpi or sw

Tags: android

what is the difference between `layout-ldpi` and `layout-sw320`.I mean when to use `ldpi,mdpi,hdpi,xhdpi` and when to use `layout-sw`?

Which one is to be used for the current version of android?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Drawable-hdpi, Drawable-mdpi, Drawable-ldpi Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3263265/drawable-hdpi-drawable-mdpi-drawable-ldpi-android)

Comment: Only difference is after and before API 13, layout-ldpi is before api level13 and layout-sw is using for versions above 13.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Main difference is after and before API 13, layout-ldpi is before api
>   level13 and layout-sw is using for versions above 13.

If you have layouts for larger screen devices such as tablets, now its the time to stop using the -large or -xlarge resource and switch to using -swXXdp or -wXXdp qualifiers. The latter were introduced in API level 13, which basically all tablets now have support for according to the latest platform version.

```
res/layout-xlarge/main_activity.xml    # For pre-3.2 tablets
res/layout-sw600dp/main_activity.xml   # For 3.2 and up tablets
```

Like

```
7" tablets: Instead of layout-large, use layout-sw600dp. 
10" tablets: Instead of layout-xlarge, use layout-sw720dp.
```

Answer (score 1):

These are different type of resource qualifiers:

- `ldpi`, `mdpi`, `hdpi`, `xhdpi` are based on the screen pixel density, and usually used for bitmap drawables.
- `sw320` (actually incorrect, it should be `sw320dp`) is based on the screen smallest size and is usually used for layout, or dimensions.

They are orthogonal, you could even have `layout-sw320dp-hdpi` (althought is usually doesn't make sense to make the layout depends on the screen density). See [Providing Alternative Resources](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources) for a complete list of qualifier types and values and how to mix them.

Answer (score 0):

All these (ldpi , hdpi , mdpi, xhdpi , xxhdpi) use to provide multi screen support , Android devices are available in various screen resolutions , so to give Same look and feel in each screen size these must use.
you may refer this,

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

http://jennift.com/dpical.html